# Track users over cross browsers for analytics

Tags: google-analytics, cross-browser, google-analytics-api, web-analytics

I want to track users (cross browsers) without a login option to perform efficient web analytics.
I went through flash cookies, but they don't sound promising!

Is there any other way to identify users (cross browsers)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one way is to use UserID - but this require use some unique identifier for each user(like login).

So without login(or other unique id for user) you can't track users across different browsers. Google Analytics will create unique cookie for each browser, so user from 2 browsers will be counted as 2 different visitors in GA. Because browsers can't share GA cookie between each other.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/user-id#clientid-userid